# How to build kernel with OpenVZ support

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, openvz

Is it possible to compile 5.x kernel with OpenVZ?

There is a full-blown custom OS built on top of RHEL6 called Virtuozzo 7.0, but it uses only 3.10 kernel. I would like to build any newer kernel, preferably 5.x, or at least one they developed at https://github.com/OpenVZ/vzkernel/tree/stable-4.14.3 and use it on Debian/Ubuntu - is this possible, and if so, which options should I select when configuring it with `make menuconfig`? I could find only old guides like https://wiki.openvz.org/Compiling_the_OpenVZ_kernel_(the_Debian_way) , which doesn't seem to apply to this repo (there is no OpenVZ option in the menuconfig).

Comment: That GitHub repo already has tags based on RHEL 8 kernels. Why do you want a new kernel on an old OpenVZ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't understand your question. I just want to be able to create linux containers, and way of achieving it is using OpenVZ. So I want kernel with latest patches and features and with VZ support so that I can create linux containers easily with their tools eg. vzctl. But maybe I am mixing the terminologies here, or just chose hard way of getting linux containers to work. Thanks

Comment: Why not just install it according to its directions, then? Why do you want to replace the kernel?

Comment: Well I tried the official OpenVZ iso if that's what you mean (called Virtuozzo 7.0 I think), but it had only 3.10 kernel - way too old. And the guide for building kernel does not work anymore.

Comment: Why do you keep saying that the kernel is way too old?